# Filter three ComboBoxes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, combobox, filtering

I have three comboBoxes I want to make them work together as filters. The first one filters the second's memberNames and depending on the seconds's SelectedValue it will filter the third's memberNames.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

This Query filters comboBox2 when the Index in comboBox1 changes. This works

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JAVIER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cafepolis;Integrated Security=True");
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (departamentoID), (departamentoNOMBRE) FROM departamentos WHERE paisID = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
   DataTable depto = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(depto);
   comboBox2.DataSource = depto;   
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

This is supposed to filter comboBox3 when comboBox2's Index has changed. This doesn't work.

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JAVIER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cafepolis;Integrated Security=True");
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT (municipioID), (municipioNOMBRE), (departamentoID) FROM municipios WHERE departamentoID = '" + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "'", con);
   DataTable municipio = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(municipio);
   comboBox3.DataSource = municipio;       
}

private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
```

The first two are working fine, it's the third comboBox I can't get to filter the data. What am I missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is the code for comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged ??

Comment: what is the query for the third issue?